# What are the things to avoid when using a IoC container?

Tags: inversion-of-control

I'm introducing an IoC Container in an architecture for the first time. I'm looking for things that one **should not** do with an IoC Container. I want to avoid the pitfalls of using an IoC container. I don't want to misuse or overuse it.

Can you help me put up a list of things to avoid when using a IoC container?

I have on item on my list so far:

- Don't let every class access the container (don't make it a public Singleton). Only a few top level classes should access the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are putting an IoC in place, I suggest you to have a look at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/YAN/IoC+Container

Here are few interesting points

> - The most obvious one, container should not require business objects
>     assembled by it to implement any
>     interface, to inherit any class, to
>     call any API. This avoids direct
>     dependency on the container.
> - The container should not require business objects to conform to any
>     coding convention, such as "you have
>     to expose public constructor", "you
>     have to expose Java Bean setters",
>     "you have to have a method named like
>     injectXXX", "you have to use a special
>     annotation" etc. Such restriction
>     places an implicit dependency on the
>     container because the programmers of
>     the business objects still have to be
>     aware of the do's and dont's from the
>     container.
> - Do not depend on any IoC container API
>     in your IoC objects. It is a tragedy
>     to violate the principle of IoC by
>     using an IoC container.
> - IoC container
>     is for the code that assembly objects
>     together; it is for the configuration
>     of the system. After all, it is not
>     for the business objects.
> - Declarative API is preferable. It is nice to expose a declarative API rather than one that requires procedural coding.

Comment: Amazedsaint: 1 - Which IoC container libraries do not require the classes to conform to some type of convention? And how do they find your "injection points" then? 2 - Can you explain what you mean by "Declarative API is preferable"? What would be the pitfalls of using another type of API?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is more simplistic than the kind of advice you're looking for, but my suggestion would be: don't get hung up on the container.

IoC is 1% about the container, and 99% about the components inside. They're what gives the application value - the container on the other hand is infrastructural junk ;)

You should be able to design those components in the most effective way for your application.

If you start out with what seems to be a good container, and have no trouble creating well-encapsulated, clean, natural components that don't depend heavily on the container API, then you're on the right track.

If, however, you find yourself jumping through hoops to fit your design into the container, and you don't think the problem is with your design, the immediately find a container without the limitation that's impacting you, and just keep moving forwards.

Hope this helps!

Nick

Answer (score 1):

I'd say don't use config files for registering types unless you absolutely have to.  It makes refactoring hard and it's also harder to unit test with your default (non mock) mappings.

Comment: Hi NotDan, why does that make it harder to unit test with the default mappings?

Comment: (At least with .NET) Your config file for your test project is different than the application config file (i.e. MyApp.exe.config vs MyTest.exe.config).  Since you are not testing with the mappings that will actually be used, you can't be sure that just because your tests pass that your app will run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The IoC container.

No, seriously; start writing everything without an IoC container.  Once you've gotten the hang of how IoC works and started using it in your code, you'll start to see the areas where the container will help.  That is when you should add the container: when you are ready to solve a real issue with the container.  Don't use a container just because someone said containers are a Good Idea™.